# What will be the matrix of an anti-selfadjoint transformation in an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

I am a bit confused by this question. The statement of the question tells me that $(x|Ty) = -(Tx|y)$ and that $B$ is an orthonormal basis. Also, that the field is $C$.

On my own, I have found that working with the given equality tells me that for $\alpha \in B$:

$\bar{a_i}$ $= -a_i$

(where $T\alpha$ $= \sum$$a_i\alpha_i$)

I also know that:
$T\alpha_j$ $= \sum(T\alpha_j | \alpha_i) \alpha_i$

I am just not sure what this is telling me about the matrix $[T]_B$

Comment: If $T$ is anti-selfadjoint then $iT$ is selfadjoint.

Comment: @KeithMcClary This is not going off what you have told me, but can I make the following argument? If $T$ is anti-selfadjoint, then you can show easily that it must be normal. By spectral theorem, $T$ is normal iff there is an orthonormal basis for $T$ consisting of its eigenvectors. Then, since we have shown that $T$ is normal, we must have that $[T]_B$ is diagonal because $B$ is the orthonormal basis.